# Blade Foreach alternating classes

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I am using a blade template and I was wanting to know within my `foreach` what the best way is for me to have it so that my first `.panel-heading` has another class added to it and then the second one has another etc

**Example:**

`.red
.blue
.red
.blue
.red`

**Code:**

```
@foreach ($dealsDB as $deal)
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i>{{ $deal->title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{ $deal->content }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: which Laravel version are you using exactly? Laravel 5.3 has a built-in foreach counter.

Comment: @MinaAbadir 5.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$k=0;
@foreach ($dealsDB as $deal)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading @if($k%2==0) red @else blue @endif">
                    <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i>{{ $deal->title }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>{{  $deal->content }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   $k++;
@endforeach
```

Comment: I will save anyone else that lands here that this just prints $k==0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@switch` inside your `@foreach` to assign different class on every iteration.

```
    @foreach (...)
         <div class="
           @switch($loop->iteration)
              @case(1)
                red
              @break
            
              @case(2)
                green
              @break
            
              @case(3)
                blue
              @break
            
              @default
                yellow
            @endswitch
        ">
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Hi Famaxis, please don't post "code-only" answers, try to provide an explanation.

Comment: @AlimGirayAytar I'm sorry. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.8+, the `$loop->odd` or `$loop->even` variables can be used for this.

Furthermore, in Laravel 8.0 the `@class` directive was added. This is the perfect use case example for it.

In Laravel 5.3+ there is the `$loop->iteration` which returns the current loop iteration (starts at 1).

Docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#conditional-classes

The following examples will return the exact same result.

**Laravel 8+ version**

```
@foreach ($dealsDB as $deal)
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div @class([
            'panel panel-default',
            'red-class' => $loop->odd,
            'blue-class' => $loop->even
        ])>
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i>{{ $deal->title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{ $deal->content }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Laravel 5.8+ Version**

```
@foreach ($dealsDB as $deal)
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default 
                 @if($loop->odd) red-class @else blue-class @endif">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i>{{ $deal->title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{ $deal->content }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Laravel 5.3+ Version**

```
@foreach ($dealsDB as $deal)
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default 
                 @if($loop->iteration % 2 == 0) blue-class @else red-class @endif">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i>{{ $deal->title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{ $deal->content }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```